# Importing rows from certain columns in another sheet based on search keyword

Tags: excel, import

I'm have total of 2 sheets in one excel file. 
One of the sheets is the main sheet and the other is basically for info's.

I have a list of numbers in the Column F of the main sheet and I have some other info's in that I need in the other sheet. 
The F in Main sheet will be the Search key.

If the info in column F in MAIN SHEET matches the info in column L of SHEET2 then import Column C,G,H,I from the same row in SHEET2.

I'm betting it's possible since it is possible in Google Spreadsheet.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: have you tried the VLOOKUP function ?

Answer (score 1):

The use of the [INDEX MATCH](http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/) approach would be best in this situation.

You don't say where you want the contents of the C, G, H, I columns in the to appear in the Main sheet so I have assumed that you want these to appear in C, G, H and I of the main sheet.

In this example there are only 6 rows of data, rows 1 to 6.  The sheet names are `Main` and `Sheet2`

Usig this formula in cell `C1` of `Main`

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!C$1:C$6, MATCH(Main!$F1, Sheet2!$L$1:$L$6, 0))
```

Will search `Sheet`2 column `L` for the value on cell `F1` of the `Main` sheet.  It will then return the corresponding row value from column `C` of `Sheet2`.

You can then copy this down Column C and into Columns G, H, and I to repeat the lookup.

Hopefully this is useful.  Please let me know if you have further questions.